# Updating tableview binded to array error

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am extremely new to Swift so I am guessing this is a rookie mistake but here's my situation:

I am trying to create an application that allows you to add things to a list.  I have a `NSTextField` where users input there data and a `NSButton` to add that data to the `myTeam` array.  The `tableView` is binded (I think that's what you call it) to the `myTeam` array.

When I run the application a table containing the preset values of `myTeam` populate the table view correctly, but when I add to this array nothing happens. After research, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37146801/how-to-update-data-in-tableview-swift?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Unfortunately, like most swift tutorials and Q&A, it was for iOS. But I thought I would give it a try. I added

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
self.refresher.endRefreshing()
```

to my code, and received two errors: `Value of type '(NSTableView, NSTableColumn?, Int) -> Any?' has no member 'reloadData'` and `Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'refresher'`, respectively.

Heres my code below:

```
import Cocoa
import Darwin

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDataSource {
 var myTeam = ["Test", "Test2"]



    @IBOutlet weak var myText: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var AddMember: NSButton!

    @IBAction func addmem(_ sender: Any) {
        myTeam.append(myText.stringValue);
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.refresher.endRefreshing()

    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
    // MARK: DataSource
    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return myTeam.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {
        return myTeam[row]
    }
}
```

P.S. I used [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6jQCLLPJ_8) tutorial to get as far as I did.

Comment: No need to import Darwin if you import Cocoa

Comment: @LeoDabus Ok. Saw that in a tutorial thought I should add it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution, we are going to use (full) Cocoa Bindings:

- Replace the entire code with

  ```
  import Cocoa

  class ViewController: NSViewController  {

      @IBOutlet weak var myText: NSTextField!

      @objc dynamic var myTeam = ["Test", "Test2"]

      @IBAction func addmem(_ sender: NSButton) {
          myTeam.append(myText.stringValue)
      }
  }
  ```
- In Interface Builder select the table view (not the enclosing scroll view) and press <kbd>⌥⌘6</kbd> (Connections Inspector)

  - Disconnect `dataSource`
- Press <kbd>⌥⌘7</kbd> (Bindings Inspector)

  - Bind *Content* to `ViewController` > *Model Key Path* `myTeam`

Since you are still using `objectValueFor` I assume that the value of the table cell view is already bound to `objectValue`.

macOS doesn't know a refresher.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. Quick question. Can you explain your code? I don't really understand most of it. For example, I removed `@objc dynamic` and the screen was blank.

Comment: Cocoa Bindings is a functionality using Key-Value-Observing. The bound values are updated automatically if the observed object has been changed. To enable KVO the data source array is required to be declared as `@objc dynamic`.

Comment: Got it. Perfect.