# Returning new Cell when new data is received in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

So I have come to a tiny stop in my app. I am currently working with a tableview to display some data that is being sent from a Arduino. Now I am manually sending it one byte array at a time to simulate, but it will eventually send a lot. Currently the app displays the data just fine, like I want it too, but I can't make it display the data in a new cell, each time I click send from the Arduino.

So in the `numberOfRowsInSection` it will return 100 cells of the same data. I want it to return 1 cell every time I send it from the Arduino. So if I click send 10 times, I want to display 10 cells, of the data that was sent.

Currently I have used: `return recievedBytes.count`, but that only counts each byte in the array. But I want a new cell, EVERYTIME a new byte array is received.

Do anyone know what I would need to return in order to do that?

Shoutout if anything is unclear.

Thanks guys

**Here is the tableview code:**

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 100 //THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP :)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RecieveCell", for: indexPath) as! RecieveTableCell
    cell.rowNumber.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1)." 
    cell.modeLabel.text = "\(recievedModeType)"
    cell.timeLabel.text = "\(String(message))μs"

    return cell
}
```

**EDIT:**

OK guys, I think I should write in some more, since I think I mislead you a bit. I've tried out what you suggested but its not quite what I was thinking. I see now I wrote it a bit misleading.

For example. I am sending from the Arduino this: [0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44,0x55,0x66,0x77]

In this I can display a MODE(recievedModeType) and a TIME(message) in the table view.

Doing what you guys suggested, I am now returning 7 cells, with one element in each cell. Because of recievedBytes.count. Its not quite what I was thinking.

What I want is to display Mode and Time in one cell, by sending that array. And it will continue to display in more cells, as long as its being sent. So in a sense, if 50 of these arrays are being sent, then I would like to have 50 cells representing the MODE and TIME.

But I will continue to look more on this now..

My apologies for the confusion.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to update data in tableview (Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37146801/how-to-update-data-in-tableview-swift)

Comment: Welcome to SO. A simple solution will be to add a `didSet` observer to the `receivedBytes` array. Something like this: `var recievedBytes = ["type of the data"]() { didSet { tableView.reloadData() } }` and keep `return recievedBytes.count` in the `numberOfRowsInSection` method

Comment: Thanks guys, this got me some ideas, excellent! Let me try a bit, and ill let you know how it goes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep track of the arrays you are are receiving you can use another array

```
var receivedArrays: [[UInt8]] = []
var receivedBytes: [UInt8] = [] {
    didSet {
        receivedArrays.append(receivedBytes)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Then you can return receivedCount as numberOfRows and use your array of receivedBytes as you wish in your cellForRowAt function.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return receivedArrays.count
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I can return one cell with the data, but when I try sending it again, it just reloads with one cell still. But I am very close now I can tell!

Comment: What do you mean by it reloads with one cell? It won't add new cells to the tableView?

Comment: I was overwriting the recievedArray every time so no wonder I only got one cell, a simple += operator in my recieveBytes function fixed it. Your answer help me out, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

basically, if you are aiming to fill the table view with *dynamically*, I would recommend to keep following the approach of: `return recievedBytes.count`, which means keep using `recievedBytes` as the data resource for filling the table view.

> but that only counts each byte in the array. But I want a new cell,
>   EVERYTIME a new byte array is received.

What you could do to resolve it is:

- update `recievedBytes` array.
- call the [`reloadData()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614862-reloaddata) method.

Although I am unaware of what is the exact type of `recievedBytes`, let's consider that is it `[Int]` to review an example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // ...

    var recievedBytes: [Int] = [] {
        didSet {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    // ...
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    // If the number of section should be 1, you don't have to implement numberOfSections
    // and let it return 1, it is the default value for it.

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return recievedBytes.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RecieveCell", for: indexPath) as! RecieveTableCell

        let currentByte = recievedBytes[indexPath.row]

        cell.rowNumber.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1)."
        cell.modeLabel.text = "\(currentByte)"
        cell.timeLabel.text = "\(String(message))μs"

        return cell
    }
}
```

Note that:

- As a good practice, for such a case it is recommended to declare `recievedBytes` as a property observer, each time `recievedBytes` gets updated `tableView.reloadData()` will get called.
- `recievedBytes` should be also reliable when dealing with `cellForRowAt` method, `currentByte` should be the byte in `recievedBytes` based on the current row, therefore you could display its value.

Comment: var receivedBytes: [UInt8] is used in a function where I get the acual message, where in this case it is Time in μs. But I´ll look at this you wrote, thanks!

Comment: @Wolfgang glad to help. If my answer answered your question please don't forget to accept it ;)